# Delphi Chromium Embedded on DLL Form

Tags: delphi, dll, tchromium

I have an application that uses VCL forms from DLL. On one of the forms I placed TChromium from DelphiChromiumEmbedded. There is a problem: when I unload my DLL (form destroyed), the application freezes without any errors or AVs. I found some answer - commented //cef_shutdown in the lib_cef.pas. In this path form successful destroyed, but I have big memory leak. With other any components creating form from DLL, destroying and unloading the DLL are successful.

How I can normally unload DLL with form with TChromium component?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have a need to create objects for DLL's case similar mistakes in effecting unload the DLL.

If you created the instance of the application object, destroy instantiates the application before performing the unload the DLL.